# IDE для современного изучения ассемблера [любого]

Tags: ассемблер

Очень хотелось бы ознакомиться с языками ассемблера, особенно интересно было использовать блоки _asm в VS C++, но этого очень мало. А из того, что я слышал, чуть ли не под DOS писать код. Но ведь никуда ассемблер не делся, значит и IDE существуют, а я слышал только о [SASM](https://habr.com/ru/post/230359/).

Comment: Чтобы ознакомиться с языками ассемблера IDE особо не нужен. Для набора текста подойдёт любой редактор с поддержкой Auto Ident, например Notepad++. Компилировать через командную строку - для автоматизации можно использовать батники. Я в своё время так поступал, и потом привык. А вообще, самой популярной средой разработки на ассемблере под винду был RadASM: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/RadASM. Правда не знаю, поддерживается ли этот пакет сейчас...

Comment: Спасибо. А зачем такие сложности с досом обычно?

Comment: Какие сложности с досом? DOS - 16-битная операционная система, которая работает в древнем 16-битном режиме процессора (либо в виртуальной машине, эмулирующей 16-битный режим). Процесс изучения ассемблера в ВУЗах обычна предполагает сначала написание 16-битных программ под DOS, затем - 32-битных под Windows. Если желаете изучить ассемблер чисто для себя, то можно сразу начинать писать под Windows, однако я бы посоветовал для начала найти хороший учебник по Ассемблеру и методично идти по нему.

Comment: В VS есть поддержка .asm исходников (для MASM) из коробки, а блоки _asm (__asm) в C++ использовать как раз не стоит. При отладке имеет смыл открыть окошко с регистрами.

Comment: Берите любой редактор кода (хоть VS code, хоть Sublime Text, хоть Notepad++). По сути редактор + командная строка + внешний отладчик - это IDE для ассемблера.